# MongoDB database design, Is redundancies important?

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I have a question about MongoDB database design.
As far as I know (I'm not sure I'm correct), there is no need to use relationships between collections. For example I have collection for Users with their emails and there are email templates that I want to send them to the users.
Should I use my old paradigm of avoiding redundancies and design 3 collections like this:

```
Users:  ID,Name,Email
Templates: ID,Contents
EmailSent: UserID,TemplateID
```

Or should use Nosql paradigm like this:

```
Users:  ID,Name,Email
Templates: ID,Contents
EmailSent: UserID,Contents
```

Difference is only in Email sent collection. I'm looking for a clear answer according to MongoDB design architecture, not personal opinions

Comment: NoSQL is a very broad category of database types. So there may well be a specific answer for MongoDB (and perhaps you should tag your question with mongdb) but not for NoSQL in general. What is optimal for MongoDB may not work so well for Cassandra, Neo4J, CouchBase, etc.

Comment: I agree with DNA. I took the liberty of replacing "NoSQL" with "MongoDB" in the question, because this will provide you much more useful answers. I also replaced "Table" with "Collection", because that's the correct terminology in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this special case, I would not reference the used template from the sent emails, because a sent email is sent and can not be changed anymore. When you change the template after sending an email, the email already in the inbox of the receiver would not change. But when you look at the email in your application, it would appear with the new template even though that's not the template which was active when the email was generated. That would provide your users with misleading information.

In the more general case, there is no by-the-book solution for the question embedding vs. referencing. While MongoDB generally prefers embedding over referencing because of the lack of on-database JOINs, embedding causes problems when many documents embed copies of the same data and that data changes. In that case you either have to leave the data as-is (which can make sense in some cases, like here for example) or update all documents when you update the embedded data. This would be an expensive operation.

You won't have that costly mass-update operation with referencing instead of embedding. However, it would makes retrieval of the complete documents more expensive because you would have to perform multiple subsequent queries.

Which option you choose depends on your expected usual use-case:

- When you expect that requesting with the sub-document is a frequent operation and updating the subdocument is a rare operation, you would choose embedding.
- When the sub-document changes very frequently and requests are rare, referencing would be the smarter strategy.